# Different button behavior for Chrome vs IE11

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, submit-button

I have a form with a button, and some jquery to handle the click event of the button. In IE, the click event runs, and then the form submits (because the default button behavior since IE8 is to submit the form). In Chrome however, the form submit never happens.

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    $("#btnAdd").prop('disabled', true);
});

<form>
    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</form>
```

It appears that this is related to disabling the button. Is it expected behavior that in Chrome, a button that is disabled onclick will not automatically submit, but in IE, it doesn't matter if the button is disabled or not?

Comment: You mention IE11 in your question title but in the body reference IE8? which are you asking about (or is it both)?

Comment: You should listen to the `submit` event of the `<form>`, and not to the `click` event of the `<button>`.

Comment: I am comparing Chrome to IE11; the behavior I see in IE11 is the expected behavior for IE8 and later.

Comment: listen to the `submit` event not the click event. that is more accurate either way. If you want to do stuff before the submit then you need to prevent the submit and then force it to submit on complete.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I'm using Chrome 38.0.2125.111 and your code writes to the console and submits the form.

Comment: @showdev, sorry I'd simplified the example, but apparently I missed the key part. The onclick event disables the button (to prevent double-clicking).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an `onsubmit` event attached to the form itself. That way, you can prevent the default submission, disable the button, then submit the form programatically.

I have used jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so the handler will run only once. Otherwise, the programatic submission will also trigger the event and create an infinite loop.

```js
$("#form").one('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#btnAdd").prop('disabled', true);
    console.log('clicked');
    // Below, to submit the form
    $(this).submit();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</form>
```

In the jsfiddle below, I have used a `setTimeout` to delay the programatic form submission. This is just to demonstrate separation of the two actions: disable button and submit.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mL29ajqq/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I actually used <button type="button"> and then submitted programatically onclick, which achieved the same results. But my main question is why Chrome and IE have different behavior here, and if that is expected behavior; or a weird bug.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be informative: [Bug 14443 - Forms dont submit when disabling submit button](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14443)

Answer (score -1):

**Edited:**
Instead of button, try :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add" />
    </form>
```

It works in all browsers.

**Edit**: Didn't read your question well, sorry... this one works for me.
[code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qw7p21c6/)